# How to get end time of previous job

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a task which is scheduled every few minutes.

I want to implement the logic where new task starts where previous successfully executed task left off.

More concretely I use this time intervals to than query the database and so I don't to miss some data between executions.

How this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation around macros](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#default-variables). You can see that you have two variables that you can use in your sql files: `{{ execution_date }}` and `{{ next_execution_date }}` - you should use these to query the database for the time interval like this for example:

```
select * 
from 
  table
where
  timestamp_column >= {{ execution_date }} 
  and timestamp_column < {{ next_execution_date }}
```

Comment: Of course it wouldn't, if you do a manual run and set the execution_date manually Airflow can't magically assume what you want for the next execution date... How would you do this in any other tool?

Comment: I meant when there is a schedule interval set and you also sometimes start manually in between.

Comment: I think you might have to update your question with an example since I don't really understand